# Chrome extension and .click() loops using values from localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, onclicklistener

I have made a Chrome extension to help using a small search engine in our company's intranet. That search engine is a very old webpage really convoluted, and it doesn't take parameters in the url. No chance that the original authors will assist:

- The extension popup offers an input text box to type your query. Your
  query is then saved in `localStorage`
- There is a content script inserted in
  the intranet page that reads the localStorage key and does a `document.getElementById("textbox").value = "your query";` and then does
  `document.getElementById("textbox").click();`

The expected result is that your search is performed. And that's all.

The problem is that the click gets performed unlimited times in an infinite loop, and I cannot see why it's repeating.

I would be grateful if you would be able to assist. This is my first Chrome extension and all what I have been learning about how to make them has been a great experience so far.

This is the relevant code:

The extension popup where you type your query

`popup.html`

```
<input type="search" id="cotext"><br>
<input type="button" value="Name Search" id="cobutton">
```

The attached js of the popup

`popup.js`

```
var csearch = document.getElementById("cotext");
var co = document.getElementById("cobutton");
co.addEventListener("click", function() {
    localStorage["company"] = csearch.value;
    window.open('url of intranet that has content script applied');
});
```

And now the background file to help with communication between parts:

`background.js`

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
});
```

And finally the content script that is configured in the manifest to be injected on the url of that search engine.

`incomingsearch.js`

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(
{method: "getLocalStorage", key: "company"},
    function(response) {
    var str = response.data;
    if (document.getElementById("txtQSearch").value === "") {
        document.getElementById("txtQSearch").value = str;
    }
    document.getElementById("btnQSearch").click();
    });
```

So as I mentioned before, the code works... not just once (as it should) but many many times. Do I really have an infinite loop somewhere? I don't see it... For the moment I have disabled .click() and I have put .focus() instead, but it's a workaround. I would really like to use .click() here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` is deprecated already. Use `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` instead. Also for the `chrome.extension.sendRequest`. Use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` instead. See reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is probably caused by clicking the button even if it has a value. Try putting it inside your if. That said, you are overcomplicating it.

You can access the extension's data inside content scripts directly by replacing localstorage with the [chrome.storage extension api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Add the "storage" (silent) permission to your manifest.json, like this:

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

Remove the message passing code in background.js. Then replace the popup button listener contents with:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ "company": csearch.value }, function() {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "whatever url" })
})
```

Replace the content script with:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("company", function(items) {
  if(document.querySelector("#txtQSearch").value == "") {
    document.querySelector("#txtQSearch").value = items.company
    document.querySelector("#btnQSearch").click()
  }
})
```

[document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) performs the same function here as getElementById, but it is much more robust. It also has less capital letters, which makes it easier to type in my opinion.

Comment: Excellent! It worked perfectly. Probably if you had only mentioned the loop problem it would have been fine, but in addition I also loved learning about chrome.storage. I'll be sure to use it in next projects!, thanks!